# Writing data to a text files and accessing it inside am iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode

I have a swift app that prints the position and rotation of the camera in the console as long as the app is running. I want to have this printout be saved to a file that's exportable from the app. Would integration with the Files app be the best way to do this? Can I even have a constantly updating set of data write to a file like I'm describing?

Thanks!

Comment: "integration with the Files app" that's usually for document-based apps, like Pages or GarageBand. If you just want to export a file, [`UIActivityViewController`](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/118/uiactivityviewcontroller-by-example) should be enough.

Comment: The idea is that the app records position and rotation that can then be exported for use on a separate computer as a .txt file.

Comment: What method are you thinking of using to get that txt file to the other computer? Are you just wanting to save the file to the phone then move it over by connecting your phone to that computer? Or are you wanting to send that file over the internet?

Comment: I want to save it to the Files app, which is linked to iCloud, so it's accessable on any computer with an iCloud account.